# Remote lecturing: best software approach

Tags: software, lecture-teaching-method, remote-work, covid-19

With the recent outbreak of covid-19 many of us will need to think about remote means of teaching.

The option for me that seems ideal would be the capacity to broadcast exactly what is on my screen to a a large audience (a minimum of a couple of dozen).

There seems to me an ideal solution, but there are a dizzying number of options available, many of which do not quite fit that spec. Software that is free and readily available to educational institutions (such as something on google apps) would be ideal of course.

Comment: Why software? why not have work files with clear instructions...

Comment: Please see [this Meta discussion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4675/7734) on such questions. We already have two (closed) questions on this. Whether these should be closed or not, it makes little sense to add a third.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft oh perhaps... just hear me out now... someone with experience of this could provide an answer to the question, I'll give them an upvote if I think it's a good answer and accept it if I think it is practical.

Comment: @SolarMike well one would require software of some kind, be it a stand alone program or one that runs in a browser. Hell, even if you host a pdf on a server that would technically require software (a web server at my end and browser at the user's end) for it to work

Comment: @Stumbler: Well, hear me out: You could provide good arguments in that Meta discussion or just upvote an answer supporting such questions. You can also check the existing questions whether any of the answers and comments there help you. Finally, you may [edit] your question to clarify why your question is different than the existing ones.

Comment: @Stumbler you would also need some operating system to run the browser or ftp software...